# sbt doesn't recognize external library

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using IntelliJ, and the sbt shell. I added an external jar to my project via Project Structure, and then ran `sbt assembly`. My code looks something like this:

```
package myPackage

import com.myExternalPackage.stuff

// implementation using com.myExternalPackage.stuff
```

IntelliJ recognizes this external jar and there are no red lines in the IDE. If I CTRL-click on `myExternalPackage` in the editor, it even opens up the exact place in External Libraries where the package is coming from.

But `sbt assembly` complains that

> object myExternalPackage is not a member of package com

Do I need to do something to my build.sbt? Other people in my company are using this code without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.sbt`, you should have:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.myExternalPackage" % "xxxx" % "version"
)
```